# How to run multiple publishers at the same time paho-mqtt?

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I am running a single script with several clients publishing to the same topic, 5 messages each, but they do it one after another. I would like to know if there is any way to execute several publishers but at the same time and not for a loop "for "as I programmed it.

It occurred to me to run various python scripts but it is not functional if I want to have for example 100 publishers. Anyone have an idea how I could do it? Thanks in advance

```
import ssl
import time 
import random
import sys  
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from datetime import datetime

broker_address = '127.0.0.1'
topic = "casa/hab1"
port=1883
delay=0.2
count=0
i=0
j=0
nclients=1
nmessages=5


for i in range(nclients):
  cname="Client"+str(i) 
  j=int(time.time()) #eliminar la parte decimal
  j=str(j)
  client_id=cname+str(j)+"_" #generar client_id
  client=mqtt.Client(client_id) 
  client.connect(broker_address)  
  print("")

  print(str(client_id))
  client.loop_start() 

  for count in range(nmessages):
     b=random.randrange(10, 99, 1)
     mensaje="Hello World:"+ str(b)+" -- "
     client.publish(topic,mensaje, 2, retain=False) 
     now=datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
     print("timestamp "+str(count)+" = "+now)
     
     count+=1
     time.sleep(delay)

  i+=1
```

Comment: Please do NOT post images of code, it is really hard to read and impossible for those that use screen readers. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63890677/edit) the question to include the actual text and use the toolbar to format it properly.

Comment: If you want to do things concurrently you will need to learn how to use threads

Comment: I'm sorry, I just edited the post and published the code.

Comment: if you have to run it in one script the you will have to use module `threading` or `multiprocessing` to run every publisher in separated thread/process. You may also check in documentation if you can create own `loop` instead of `loop_start()` and run all clients in one loop - and then you have to  first create all clients and keep on list and later you can use this list to publish at the same time - using own `loop` instead of `loop_start()`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally to run many functions at the same time you would need to use `threading` or `multiprocessing` to run every function in separated `thread`/`process`.

But `client.loop_start()` already runs `thread` so you can first create many clients,

```
all_clients = []

for i in range(nclients):
    t = int(time.time())

    client_id= "Client_{}_{}_".format(i, t) 
    print('create:', client_id)
    
    client = mqtt.Client(client_id) 
    client.connect(broker_address)  
    client.loop_start() 

    all_clients.append([client_id, client])
```

and later use them in loop which sends messages

```
for count in range(nmessages):

    for client_id, client in all_clients: 
        b = random.randrange(10, 99, 1)
        mensaje = "Hello World: {} -- ".format(b)
        client.publish(topic, mensaje, 2, retain=False) 
        now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        print('client:', client_id, '| count:', count, "=", now)

    time.sleep(delay)
```

It will send almost in the same time (+- 0.01s) but running every `client` in separated `thread`/`process` to would be harder to run messages with so small delay.

---

```
import time 
import random
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from datetime import datetime

broker_address = '127.0.0.1'
#broker_address = '192.168.1.91'

topic = "casa/hab1"
delay = 0.2

nclients = 3
nmessages = 5

# --- first create all clients ----

all_clients = []
for i in range(nclients):
    t = int(time.time())

    client_id= "Client_{}_{}_".format(i, t) 
    print('create:', client_id)
    
    client = mqtt.Client(client_id) 
    client.connect(broker_address)  
    client.loop_start() 

    all_clients.append([client_id, client])

# ---

print()

# --- loop ---

for count in range(nmessages):

    for client_id, client in all_clients: 
        b = random.randrange(10, 99, 1)
        mensaje = "Hello World: {} -- ".format(b)
        client.publish(topic, mensaje, 2, retain=False) 
        now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        print('client:', client_id, '| count:', count, "=", now)

    time.sleep(delay)
```

Result:

```
create: Client_0_1600159539_
create: Client_1_1600159539_
create: Client_2_1600159539_

client: Client_0_1600159539_ | count: 0 = 2020-09-15 10:45:39.125615
client: Client_1_1600159539_ | count: 0 = 2020-09-15 10:45:39.126737
client: Client_2_1600159539_ | count: 0 = 2020-09-15 10:45:39.128049
client: Client_0_1600159539_ | count: 1 = 2020-09-15 10:45:39.329731
client: Client_1_1600159539_ | count: 1 = 2020-09-15 10:45:39.330702
client: Client_2_1600159539_ | count: 1 = 2020-09-15 10:45:39.332028
client: Client_0_1600159539_ | count: 2 = 2020-09-15 10:45:39.533360
client: Client_1_1600159539_ | count: 2 = 2020-09-15 10:45:39.534323
client: Client_2_1600159539_ | count: 2 = 2020-09-15 10:45:39.535380
client: Client_0_1600159539_ | count: 3 = 2020-09-15 10:45:39.737049
client: Client_1_1600159539_ | count: 3 = 2020-09-15 10:45:39.738118
client: Client_2_1600159539_ | count: 3 = 2020-09-15 10:45:39.739249
client: Client_0_1600159539_ | count: 4 = 2020-09-15 10:45:39.941419
client: Client_1_1600159539_ | count: 4 = 2020-09-15 10:45:39.943207
client: Client_2_1600159539_ | count: 4 = 2020-09-15 10:45:39.944785
```

---

**EDIT:**

The same using `threading`.

In this version you can use random `delay` in every `client` to make all traffic more random.

```
import time 
import random
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from datetime import datetime
import threading

broker_address = '127.0.0.1'
#broker_address = '192.168.1.91'

topic = "casa/hab1"
delay = 0.2

nclients = 3
nmessages = 5

# --- functions ---

def sending(client, client_id):

    for count in range(nmessages):

        b = random.randrange(10, 99, 1)
        mensaje = "Hello World: {} -- ".format(b)
        client.publish(topic, mensaje, 2, retain=False) 
        now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        print('client: {} | count: {} = {}'.format(client_id, count, now))
        #delay = random.randint(1, 5) / 10

        time.sleep(delay)

# --- first create all clients ----

all_clients = []
for i in range(nclients):
    t = int(time.time())

    client_id= "Client_{}_{}_".format(i, t) 
    print('create:', client_id)
    
    client = mqtt.Client(client_id) 
    client.connect(broker_address)  
    client.loop_start() 

    all_clients.append([client_id, client])

# ---

print()

# --- threads ---

all_threads = []

# start threads
for client_id, client in all_clients:
    t = threading.Thread(target=sending, args=(client, client_id))
    t.start()
    all_threads.append(t)
    
# ... other code ...

# at the end wait for end of threads
for t in all_threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I started to read how to use the threads and process in paho-clients, but I needed examples.
Thanks for your contributions!